# Javascript issue in firefox appending a link tag

Tags: javascript, dom

I have some code running that appends a link tag to my head, and it works fine in all browsers except Firefox, i think it may be because i use appendChild() which puts the link in the end of the head, after all the other link tag i have added, and that this last stylesheet is setting some css that some of the other stylesheets are depending on. But im not sure. Basically it is the styling of a text area that i am using jHtmlArea to generate, and jHtml has its own stylesheet that i link to, but i need to add my own stylesheet, depending on the browser that the user is viewing the page in. anyway the code looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JHTML Test!</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jHtmlArea-0/style/jHtmlArea.css" />
    <link href="jBox-0.2.0/Source/jBox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.1/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.1/extensions/TableTools/css/dataTables.tableTools.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.1/extensions/ColReorder/css/dataTables.colReorder.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.1/extensions/ColVis/css/dataTables.colVis.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script language="javascript">
        // Browsercheck
        var browser="";
        var version="";
        var href="";
        if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident") >= 0) //Versions 7-11 has Trident in userAgent but 6 does not!
        {
            browser = "ie";
            //version = "11";
            if(navigator.appName.indexOf("Netscape") >= 0) 
            {
                version="11";
                href = "css/style" + browser + version + ".css";
            } else if(navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet Explorer") >= 0) 
            {
                if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7.0") >= 0)
                { //Dont know if we support or should be left out.
                    version="7";
                    href = "css/style" + browser + version + ".css";
                } else if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 8.0") >= 0)
                {
                    version="8";
                    href = "css/style" + browser + version + ".css";
                } else if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 9.0") >= 0)
                {
                    version="9";
                    href = "css/style" + browser + version + ".css";
                } else if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 10.0") >= 0)
                {
                    version="10";
                    href = "css/style" + browser + version + ".css";
                }
            }
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") >= 0) 
        {
            if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("OPR") >= 0) 
            {
                browser="opera";
                href = "css/style" + browser + ".css";
            } else 
            {
                browser="chrome";
                href = "css/style" + browser + ".css";
            }
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") >= 0) 
        {
            browser="firefox";
            href = "css/style" + browser + ".css";
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") >= 0) 
        {
            browser="safari";
            href = "css/style" + browser + ".css";
        } else 
        {
            alert("This only supports MSIE version 7-11, Chrome, Firefox, Safari or Opera!");
            //alert("Information og the browser:\nThe code name of this browser is: " + navigator.appCodeName + "\nThe name of this browser is: " + navigator.appName + "\nThe version of this browser is: " + navigator.appVersion + "\nThe user agent header of this browser looks like this:\n" + navigator.userAgent);
            self.close();
        }
        var cssStyle = document.createElement("link");
        cssStyle.type = "text/css";
        cssStyle.rel = "stylesheet";
        cssStyle.href = href;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssStyle);
    </script>
    <div>
        <div id="top">
            <div id="mailheader">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>
                                To:
                            </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="tooltip" data-jbox-content="Input the recipient of the mail here!" id="toTF" type="text" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>
                                cc:
                            </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="tooltip" data-jbox-content="Input the cc of the mail here!" id="ccTF" type="text"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>
                                subject:
                            </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="tooltip" data-jbox-content="Input the subject of the mail here!" id="subjectTF" type="text"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mailbody">
            <textarea id="mailbodytextarea">

            </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
```

of cause there is more code, but that code is working perfectly and has to do with the DataTables framework that i am also using. Basically what i would like to do is to add the stylesheet link to the head as the first child, or between the meta and first link tags, but really who cares about that.

I hope there is someone around that can help me with this problem, i dont mind if the problem is solved using JQuery, while i am also importing JQuery libraries in the end of the body tag. If you need any more info of any kind just ask for it. If the code looks a little weird and useless, it might be because this is a sandbox for testing out how to implement into a larger system that i would prefer not to mess up while trying out things with these three new frameworks.

I just tried to hardcode the link to be in the position that i think it should be in and that seems to work in firefox, so the solutions seems to be correct, but i dont know how to put it where it will work :-)

Ok, so further i have managed to add the right things into the the link tag by creating a link tag with all the attributes and id but an empty href attribute, and setting it with a getElementById, but now it seems that i have to somehow refresh the page without setting the  href once more...

```
<link id="usersheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
```

and then later in the code, after checking for the browser:

```
document.getElementById("usersheet").href = href;
```

This might not be a very good solution, but it solved some of my problem, but it still is not working :-)

Comment: yuck, you have different CSS files for each browser?  in any case, you need to define "not working" better

Comment: Ok, basically it seems that the styling of the Datatables which sets the size of the textarea and toolbar is set before the real size of the text area is set and therefor gets a standard size of 117px width, but then afterwards the size of the div that it resides in is set to 100%, and the height is set to 200px, this makes it a very small textarea surrounded by a lot of white space... will post a screendump...

Comment: well, since my reputation is not 10 i can't post pictures...

Comment: Ok, i solved this, by loading a stylesheet right in the beginning setting the sizes of the div, before the stylesheet that set the size of the textarea depending on the div. So i consider this done!

Comment: Anyway regarding the comment on different css files for each browser; yes i know it is not a very elegant solution and it is definately not very future proof, but that is why i am looking into http://modernizr.com/ and http://yepnopejs.com/. These seem to be pretty good for support of most browsers. Even though i doubt it will solve stuff like different browsers interpretation of for instance width: 50%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved this, by loading a stylesheet right in the beginning setting the sizes of the div, before the stylesheet that set the size of the textarea depending on the div. So i consider this done!